# Getting associated GO:IDs for a given gene name using R bioconductor annotation package

Tags: r, annotations, bioconductor

I am trying to play around with hgu95av2.db and GO.db libraries from Bioconductor classes.

I have a list of genenames.

```
Genename1
Genename2
Genename3
```

These are standard gene names from genedb.

I now want to get the associated go.ids associated with them. I would like to use this information to bin the data in the future.

I have attempted to go through the annotationapi help file where they say one way of getting the ids is to use this api as follows:

```
select(hgu95av2.db, keys=keys, cols=c("GO"),
  keytype="GENENAME")
```

I am not sure how to set up the keys.
Do I just set up a column object with the list of keys.

When I try to do and run the command above I get the following error:

> Error in .testIfKeysAreOfProposedKeytype(x, keys, keytype) : 
>     None of the keys entered are valid keys for the keytype specified.

I have played around with the keytype and always get the same error which makes me think I dont really understand fundamentally how to use this database query tool.

I have done a search in bioconductor and they just assume that I have expression data in affy matrix format where I just have a list of the genenames.

I would appreciate your help and apologies as I am a newbie and not really clear on the R bioconductor interface.

Many thanks

Comment: It would be nice with some more code to work with. Could you show how you get `hgu95av2.db`? Should no solution comes up here you can also try asking on [BioStar](http://biostars.org).

Comment: Rather than asking on BioStar, the preferred forum for Bioconductor questions is the [Bioconductor mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/). What really are your `Genename1` identifiers? I'd bet `SYMBOL`, but ...; try `head(keys(hgu95av2.db, "SYMBOL"))` with several different keytypes. Also, are you really using genes from this array, or is it `org.Hs.eg.db`, i.e., humans? Or some other organism?